# Push to mercurial fails

Tags: mercurial, push

mercurial 3.0.3 running locally on Ubuntu 12.04 with https.

website runs fine with https and hg clone https://site/repo works fine with the authentication.

after adding a few files and trying to push these files I get this error after authentication

abort: destination does not support push

If I clone/ push locally on the server (through putty) with paths instead of https it works fine.

eg.

```
hg clone /home/repo/myProject
```

any idea why I cannot push over https?

(edit.)
Just enabled verbose on the client and now I can see another message. just after authentication

```
(falling back to static-http) 
abort: destination does not support push
```

Comment: Your destination does not support push, or push is disabled (pushing locally via paths always works).  Did you set up the repo yourself (e.g. on AWS), or are you using someone else's hosted Mercurial service (e.g. Bitbucket)?  If the former, how did you set it up, exactly?

Comment: I followed this guide https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/mercurial-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-with-web-access

The server is locally and I think I have enabled push as my hgrc file include Allow_push = *

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I've made some error configurations in my apache default setup. I tried to redirect user to the repo folder, but for some reason I have to use ScriptAlias - eg. https://mydomain/Alias

After this change everything worked like a charm.